# Problem using isnull and & operator in pandas to filter multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

When using -

```
1000.0 > 0 and (pd.notnull(float('nan')))
```

The output is False. but when using

```
1000.0 > 0 & (pd.notnull(float('nan')))
```

output is True. why so? and how can we use '&' operator and also check for not nulls to filter out a dataframe.
example -

```
df['output'] = df[a > 100 & (pd.notnull(b))]
```

Comment: Use more parentheses.

Comment: [Order of operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). `&` has higher precedence than `>`. Which means this `1000.0 > 0 & (pd.notnull(float('nan')))` is actually this `1000.0 > (0 & pd.notnull(float('nan')))`

Comment: The () become doubly important when either relation involves a pandas Series (or array) - i.e. multiple values.

Comment: `df['output'] = df[(a > 100) & pd.notnull(b)]`